# Python - aiohttp - Why won't my tests run?

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, github, aiohttp

I have downloaded the code here https://github.com/aosabook/500lines.

This is an educational open source project with many sub-projects. The one I am studying currently is the 'crawler' project. It requires python 3.4+ and aiohttp 1.2+. My current setup is Windows 10, Python 3.6.1, and aiohttp 2.0.4.

Strangely, my tests do not run and it is related to aiohttp. Can anybody familiar with aiohttp tell me why?

Here is the output I get:

```
C:\Users\Primary User\Desktop\500lines-master\crawler\code>python test.py
C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web.py:54: ResourceWarning: loop argument is deprecated
  warnings.warn("loop argument is deprecated", ResourceWarning)
E.E..EEEEEEEEEE..
======================================================================
ERROR: test_content_type (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 314, in test_content_type
    self.add_page(content_type='foo')
  File "test.py", line 93, in add_page
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_encoding (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 309, in test_encoding
    test_charset('', 'utf-8')
  File "test.py", line 305, in test_charset
    self.add_page(url, content_type=content_type)
  File "test.py", line 93, in add_page
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_link (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 126, in test_link
    self.add_page('/', ['/foo'])
  File "test.py", line 93, in add_page
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_link_cycle (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 137, in test_link_cycle
    url = self.add_page('/foo', ['/bar'])
  File "test.py", line 93, in add_page
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_max_tasks (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 264, in test_max_tasks
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_max_tries (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 281, in test_max_tries
    self.add_handler('/', handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_non_html (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 322, in test_non_html
    self.add_page('/xml', body=body, content_type='application/xml')
  File "test.py", line 93, in add_page
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_non_http (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 333, in test_non_http
    self.add_page(body=body)
  File "test.py", line 93, in add_page
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_prohibited_host (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 152, in test_prohibited_host
    self.add_page('/', ['http://example.com'])
  File "test.py", line 93, in add_page
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_redirect (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 196, in test_redirect
    url = self.add_redirect('/', foo)
  File "test.py", line 101, in add_redirect
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_redirect_cycle (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 214, in test_redirect_cycle
    url = self.add_redirect('/bar', foo)
  File "test.py", line 101, in add_redirect
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_redirect_join (__main__.TestCrawler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 230, in test_redirect_join
    self.add_redirect('/foo', baz)
  File "test.py", line 101, in add_redirect
    self.add_handler(url, handler)
  File "test.py", line 76, in add_handler
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 823, in add_route
    resource = self.add_resource(path, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 787, in add_resource
    self.register_resource(resource)
  File "C:\Users\Primary User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py", line 762, in register_resource
    "Cannot register a resource into frozen router.")
RuntimeError: Cannot register a resource into frozen router.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 17 tests in 0.034s

FAILED (errors=12)

C:\Users\Primary User\Desktop\500lines-master\crawler\code>
```

Comment: The sample code uses Python 3.4 and aiohttp 0.21. When I configured a Conda environment with these settings, it passes the tests. It's not clear why `requirements.txt` specifies `aiohttp>=0.21`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also learning it. I found this issue https://github.com/hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot/pull/655. Then code like this

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def _create_server(self):
    app = web.Application(loop=self.loop)
    return app

def add_handler(self, url, handler):
    self.app.router.add_route('GET', url, handler)
    handler_factory = self.app.make_handler(debug=True)
    srv = yield from self.loop.create_server(
        handler_factory, '127.0.0.1', self.port)

    # Prevent "Task destroyed but it is pending" warnings.
    self.addCleanup(lambda: self.loop.run_until_complete(
        handler_factory.finish_connections()))

    self.addCleanup(srv.close)
```

I think you should run `crawl.py`. Another problem, aiohttp 2.0.4 has no results after running for me. Using aiohttp 0.21 fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I found out I should use aiohttp 0.21 a few days ago:)Now the only problem that I have is the crawler getting stuck in loops. For example, it doesn't finish crawling dropbox.com even after running half an hour with a faster internet connection and speedy 6700K (8 core i7) processor. The readme claims it will crawl dropbox.com in less than a minute. However, it does crawl xkcd.com in about the amount of time as the readme claims it will. Have you had more success than that?